# Using Strings for uint256 not working with ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft, openzeppelin

just like the title says I cannot get using Strings to compile, I keep getting the identifier not found.
This is the start of my .sol contract

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/StringsUpgradeable.sol";

contract NFT is Initializable, StringsUpgradeable, ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
using Strings for uint256;
```

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to construct it as solidity object? Im sorry, but this is not a clean code and lacks lots of valuable pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imported `StringsUpgradeable.sol` file contains a library named `StringsUpgradeable` - not `Strings`.

Also, since it's a library, it cannot be inherited from, so you need to remove it from the list of the `NFT` parents.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/StringsUpgradeable.sol";

// removed `StringsUpgradable` from the parents list
contract NFT is Initializable, ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {

    // replaced `Strings` to `StringsUpgradable`
    using StringsUpgradeable for uint256; 
}
```

Comment: Hey man just noticed you've answered multiple questions of mine, thanks a lot you are a lifesaver!